# multiply excel if function

Tags: excel, function

i hope im right here.

im sitting here now since hours and i do not figure it out to get a if ( or in german wenn ) function.

i would like to have a commission.

for example

if someone earns 6000€ he would get 10% if its 10.000€ 16% , if its 15.000 18% and by 20000 20%.

all i get is this one here `=WENN(J13>6000;J13*10%)` but if i put more lines into im getting an error message

Comment: *What* error message? Show the *full* formula you've tried.

Comment: its written there . =WENN(J13>6000;J13*10%). the error message is just that there is something wrong with the function.

in J13 is the value.

Comment: @user342763 I thought you wrote you got the error if you "put more lines into".  Does this formula also give you that error?

Comment: =WENN(J13>6000;J13*10%;WENN(J13>10000;J13*16%))

thats what i got now. and i do not get an error. but excel ignores the 16% . it always takes the 10% , even if its more than 10000

Comment: Because the first condition *always* wins. That's your issue.

Comment: @user342763 The formula is evaluated from left to right, so the first TRUE condition will be the one returned.  You need to reverse the order of testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the formula you're looking for might be something like this:

```
=
WENN(J13>=20000;20%;
WENN(J13>=15000;18%;
WENN(J13>=10000;16%;
WENN(J13>=6000;10%;
0))))
*J13
```

However, instead of having these nested `IF`/`WENN` formulas, better use on `VLOOKUP`/`SVERWEIS`.

Store the following list in another worksheet, e.g. 'Comissions', starting in A1:
[image]

Then, use the following formula:

```
=SVERWEIS(J13;Commissions!$A$2:$B$6;2)*J13
```

The advantage of using `VLOOKUP` is that you can easily extend it and the numbers are explicitly stated outside of a formula (easier to audit later on).